# How to handle long strings in OdbcDataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

I am reading results of ODBC query into DataTable:

```
var result = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
        using (var da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
             da.Fill(result);//hangs here
        }
    }
}
```

, but it does not work for records where one of fields is long string (eg. complete email conversation pasted). Such queries never return, hang on the Fill method and ignore the  timeout. On the other hand Excel reads those records correctly when using same ODBC source.

How can I read such long strings?

Comment: What is the underlying data source that hangs?

Comment: Does it hang, or does an exception get thrown? How long have you been observing the hanging? 10 seconds? 20 seconds?
Also: How complex is your query / mind posting it?

Comment: Ben Robinson - AR System ODBC Data Source (for Remedy IT Service Management Suite from BMC Software). I believe that data source is OK since Excel is able to read all tickets.

Comment: Serv - I have left computer for 15minutes, it was still hanged. Same thing occured when I used simplified query like "SELECT HPD_Help_Desk.Detailed_Decription FROM HPD_Help_Desk WHERE HPD_Help_Desk.Incident_Number='INC0000001'"